# What method of communication does Qt use to interact with pyQt?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt5

Qt is (presumably) a set of libraries used for building GUI applications. What mechanism does Qt use for communication in the language bindings for Python? i.e. does it use the Python C API directly to creae extension modules? Does it use SWIG? Ctypes? PyBind11? I'm going to to be working with a pyQt application in the coming weeks and I havent yet worked this out. Thanks

Comment: Qt doesn't communicate anything. PyQt and PySide are *bindings* to the C++ library, they expose Qt functions and methods to python and eventually call them when related python calls are executed or attributes are referenced, but the "Qt side" doesn't know absolutely anything about the "underlying" Python interface (you probably already know what a binding does, but I explained it for other readers too). PyQt works through [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP_(software)), while PySide uses Shiboken.

Comment: I used the word *communicate* to mean the mechanism by which Python recieves information about C++ symbols etc. But yes, I mean bindings. Ultimately they all *communicate* with Python by automating the writing of the (often tedius) Python C API, and adhereing to its interfaces. Thanks for the information (answer and I'll accept).